# CKAN create API Token via CURL

Tags: ckan

Is it possible to create an API token via curl?  I tried running something like this:

```
curl -X POST -u username:password -H 'accept: application/json'  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'  -H 'content-type: application/json'  http://localhost:5000/api/3/action/api_token_create -d ' {
        "name":  "my_user_name",
        "user":"my_user"
    }'
```

Note, I tried passing in the username and password of an active account, but the command fails with an Authorization error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this error you should be authorized to make such a request. Here the steps:

1. On the CKAN ui login as admin user and go admin user profile
2. Create a api token for admin user
3. Copy this token
4. Add this admin token to your request header as
   `"Authorization":"your copied token"`

I hope this will help.